# Can I have an "If" statement in a function parameter?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'd like to use an IF statement in my VBA code where I'm calling up a Function and passing to it two parameters. The reason I need the IF statement is because the parameter is an array object that I pass to the function. Here's an abbreviation of the code that contains the problem:

```
For i = 1 To UBound(FilterArray)
    For j = LBound(ptsheets, 1) To UBound(ptsheets, 1)
        Filter_PivotField_Master _
            pvtField:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ptsheets(j, 1)).PivotTables(ptsheets(j, 2)).PivotFields(FilterArray(i, 1)), _
            FilterTypeArray:= If FilterArray(i, 2) = 1 Then
                                InvCodeArray
                                Else
                                BoardMonthArray
                                End If
    Next j
Next i
```

As you can see, I'm looping through the ptsheets array and for each entry, I'm calling up the Filter_PivotField_Master Function. The function requires two inputs (a pivotfield and a string array for the filtering). The array called "FilterArray" simply contains the info needed to pass along to the function. Because I can't seem to store the string array (either InvCodeArray or BoardMonthArray) within the "FilterArray," I wanted to use this IF statement to choose between either array based on if FilterArray(i,2) is equal to "1" or not. Is an "IF" statement option possible here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do that. Extract a method/procedure out of the inner loop, and parameterize it instead.

```
    For j = LBound(ptsheets, 1) To UBound(ptsheets, 1)
        Filter_PivotField_Master _
            pvtField:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ptsheets(j, 1)).PivotTables(ptsheets(j, 2)).PivotFields(thePivotField), _
            FilterTypeArray:= theFilterType
    Next j
```

Then have the calling code (the outer loop) implement the conditional logic that determines what parameters to give it.

```
Dim thePivotField
Dim theFilterType

For i = 1 To UBound(FilterArray)
    thePivotField = FilterArray(i, 1)
    If FilterArray(i, 2) = 1 Then
        theFiltertype = InvCodeArray
    Else
        theFilterType = BoardMonthArray
    End If
    TheExtractedMethod i, thePivotField, theFilterType
Next i
```

Your code will be much easier to follow - and to debug.

---

On a related note, I made a few assumptions just to get your snippet to compile with `Option Explicit` on (and an `IIf` instead of the illegal `If...Else` block), and [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduck-vba.com)'s last release (v1.4.3) correctly extracted the selected inner loop into its own method:

[image: Rubberduck's Extract Method refactoring tool]

There are a few known bugs with Rubberduck 1.4.3, and v2.0 is coming soon-ish, but I thought this might interest you. I don't know any other refactoring tools for VBA. Note that `Option Explicit` is pretty much a hard requirement for this to work, since Rubberduck works off *declarations* and can't resolve undeclared variables.

> Disclaimer: [I wrote this refactoring tool.](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/189/rubberduck)

Comment: Nice. I don't really understand what a 'refactoring tool' is and what purpose it serves, but I'm interested in learning more. Thanks for passing along the info.

Answer (score 4):

Use an immediate IF (IIF) for this purpose.

```
FilterTypeArray = IIF(FilterArray(i, 2) = 1, InvCodeArray, BoardMonthArray)
```

Comment: @Fadi: Thanks. I wrote *immediate IF* and then immediately typo'd the function name. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Beware though, `IIf` evaluates *both* value statements before returning, so best avoid it for anything other than constant expressions.

Comment: Thanks. The IIf function worked from a syntax perspective, but I'm getting a compile error: "Type mismatch:array or user-defined type expected"

The function is expecting an array. Can't I pass the array using this IIF approach??

Comment: I didn't look enough at the context first. This answers the question you asked (about the IF in the function call), but I don't know the answer to what you've asked in the comment, I'm afraid. What specific type of array is it expecting, and what types are InvCodeArray and BoardMonthArray?

Comment: The function I'm calling is expecting FilterTypeArray() As string.

The arrays I want to pass (InvCodeArray, etc) are both of the string type and I have validated that these arrays are set up properly and contain the strings I want to pass. This will work if I just pass InvCodeArray directly to the function. Its the use of a function like IF or IIF that is causing the error. it's as if the compiler simply expects the array object and NOT any function like IIF that would select an array object based on a value for FilterArray(i,2)

Comment: Then you need another option. (That's not the question you originally asked, though.) I'll delete my answer, but you should edit your question accordingly to explain the *actual problem* you're asking us to solve.

Comment: well, the IIF was still helpful, but I guess the real issue was the array. Re-reading my question, I think that in a general sense, I asked if what I wanted to do (using the IF) would work. It didn't, but through your help I found the true issue. I don't know what kind of edit is necessary. Thanks; I'm going to lunch!36